# Random Forest on Categorical Data with low accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to build a model that given an item, predicts which store it belongs to.

I have a data-set of ~300 records which are supposed to be items in different online stores.

Each record is composed of: Category,Sub Category,Price,Store Identifier(The y variable)

The data seems balanced as every store has around ~10 items.

With the help of @Marcus V. I succeeded encoding the categorical columns correctly. But can not produce better results than 0.52 for a RandomForest with 15 estimators and an entropy criterion.

I feel like much more can be done here. What am I missing?

This is the data: https://pastebin.com/z3eZc0vK

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion, make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

class Columns(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, names=None):
        self.names = names

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X.loc[:,self.names]

dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
dataset.columns = ["cat1", "cat2", "num1", "target"]
# dataset.columns = ["cat1", "cat2", "target"]

X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3]

labelencoder_X_0 = LabelEncoder()
X.iloc[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_0.fit_transform(X.iloc[:, 0])

labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X.iloc[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X.iloc[:, 1])

numeric = ["num1"]
categorical = ["cat1", "cat2"]

pipe = Pipeline([
    ("features", FeatureUnion([
        ('numeric', make_pipeline(Columns(names=numeric),StandardScaler())),
        ('categorical', make_pipeline(Columns(names=categorical), OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)))
    ])),
])

X = pipe.fit_transform(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 1)
classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=15, criterion='entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
accuracy = classifier.score(X_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

Comment: more data! You probably need many many more records - how many items are there? with only 300 records it is nearly impossible to differentiate between stores, especially if there are many items.

Comment: OK, But each store does not have much items. Should I duplicate records to enlarge the dataset?

Comment: with 300 records and 30 stores you can torture the as much as you want, you're not going to get good predictive power. Why are you using a random forest? Those typically need more data. Have you tried a good ol' regression or GLM? I think this is a fool's errand - collect more data before trying again.

Comment: Thanks, I surely understand your point though the reality is that there are not many items per store.. Is there a way to overcome this? Do the algorithms you suggest perform better on less samples?

Comment: Random forests rely on sampling features to determine which are "useful" and combine to lend predictive power. If you don't have a big dataset it can't differentiate between features. A regression will use all of the records and all of the features. However, you typically want to build your model on a training dataset and test on another. I don't know if this is for school or for work, but a key skill for a data scientist is to be able to say "no, this won't work". A garbage answer is more harmful than no answer at all. Pick a different dataset or tell your boss this isn't a good idea.